# How to get value of textfield on the arrow (see image below)?

Tags: javafx

Thanks, I have a question. With my program I get something like that : enter image description here

this graph generates for example the following xmi file.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYGnS.jpg)

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
  <graph:GModel xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:graph="http://de.tesis.dynaware.grapheditor.model/1.0">
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1154.0" y="551.0">
  <connectors type="tree-output" connections="//@connections.0 //@connections.1" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1275.0" y="768.0">
  <connectors type="tree-input" connections="//@connections.0"/>
  <connectors type="tree-output" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <nodes type="tree-node" x="1056.0" y="761.0">
  <connectors type="tree-input" connections="//@connections.1"/>
  <connectors type="tree-output" connectionDetachedOnDrag="false"/>
  </nodes>
  <connections type="tree-connection" source="//@nodes.0/@connectors.0" target="//@nodes.1/@connectors.0"/>
  <connections type="tree-connection" source="//@nodes.0/@connectors.0" target="//@nodes.2/@connectors.0"/>
  </graph:GModel>
```

What i want to know is to add to the xmi file information about the connection (here: value1 and value 2).

To add value 1 and value 2 i use this class

```
public class Arrow extends Group {

  private final Line line = new Line();
  private final ArrowHead head = new ArrowHead();
  public TextField txt;
  public Arrow() {
  line.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_LINE);
  head.getStyleClass().add(STYLE_CLASS_HEAD);
  txt=new TextField();
  }}
```

you can find the code here : https://github.com/tesis-dynaware/graph-editor/blob/master/api/src/main/java/de/tesis/dynaware/grapheditor/utils/Arrow.java

how can i process to add this value to the xmi file?

Thank you for your help.